# SQL Graph shortest path example

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-graph

Provide an example of using shortest path on SQL Server 2019. Technology is called SQL Graph.

```
Car -> BodyWork
 |
 V
Wheel -> Tyre
```

How do we list all parts and the associated path coming down from the root ?

Comment: you should phrase this more as a specific question. i.e. Give the setup data and then ask - How do I get the shortest path between X and Y in that?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
       ProductID int not null identity primary key,
       ProductName varchar(50) 
) AS Node;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT(ProductName) VALUES ('Car'),('BodyWork'),('Wheel'),('Tyre');

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;

CREATE TABLE HAS_PART AS EDGE;


INSERT INTO HAS_PART ($from_id, $to_id)
VALUES ((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=1), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=2))
,((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=1), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=3))
,((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=3), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductId=4));

SELECT * FROM HAS_PART;

SELECT
       P1.ProductID,
       P1.ProductName,
       COUNT(P2.ProductName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Depth],
       STRING_AGG(P2.ProductName,'->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Assembly],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.ProductID) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Product ID]
FROM
       PRODUCT P1,
       PRODUCT FOR PATH P2,
       HAS_PART FOR PATH HP
WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(P1(-(HP)->P2)+))
AND P1.ProductID = 1
ORDER BY P1.ProductID;
```

[image]